# Object is possibly 'undefined' when apply for number

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to make custom `view` component base on device size, but typescript complain about number, it said `Object is possibly 'undefined'`, here is the code

```
export interface ViewContainerProps {
  style?: ViewStyle | ViewStyle[];
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  percentWidth?: number;
  percentHeight?: number;
}
export const ViewContainer = (props: ViewContainerProps) => {
  const {style, children, percentHeight,percentWidth} = props;
  return (
    <View style={[style, {height: onePercentHeight * percentHeight}]}> // no, this number is undefined!?
      {children}
    </View>
  );
};
```

What happen, how to fix this, thank you guys a lots

Comment: Don't make it optional, or give it a default, or potentially can put a guard clause around its use--noting that until the next major TS version it doesn't dig very deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try to give a default fallback to your variable or use a non-null assertion operator

Default value: -1 can be replaced by your default value

```
variable || -1
```

non-null assertion operator  (!) at the end of variable

> (By adding the exclamation mark (!) at the end, you let the TypeScript
> compiler that there is no way this variable will be undefined or null)

```
variable!
```

Comment: So it mean " my default value is -1 , if i input variable , then value will be variable, not -1" , is that right?

Comment: Unfortunately , it show " ; expected" when i add into interface

Comment: oh not to an interface, you need to use it when you use the variable like onePercentHeight || -1

Answer (score 0):

This is because `percentWidth` and `percentHeight` are optional in props (You added the `?` when declaring them). You first have to check if these are not undefined!

If you are sure that they exist, you have to remove the question mark, or add `!` add after using them

```
<View style={[style, {height: onePercentHeight! * percentHeight!}]}> // no, this number is undefined!?
  {children}
</View>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but what "!" mean in typescript ?

Comment: it means "this will have a value, is not null, I promise"